# Combining two queries with case statement in BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm new to SQL and have been trying to combine two queries that give me a count of unique uses by day of the week ('weekday' - with days of the week coded 1-7) and by user type ('member_casual' -  member or casual user). I managed to use a case statement to combine them into one table, with the following query:

```
SELECT weekday, 
  CASE WHEN member_casual = 'member' THEN COUNT (*) END AS member_total,
  CASE WHEN member_casual = 'casual' THEN COUNT (*) END AS casual_total,
FROM
  `case-study-319921.2020_2021_Trip_Data.2020_2021_Rides_Merged`
GROUP BY  weekday, member_casual;
```

Resulting in a table that looks like this:

| Row | weekday | member_total | casual_total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | null | 330529 |
| 2 | 1 | 308760 | null |
| 3 | 2 | null | 188687 |
| 4 | 2 | 316228 | null |
| 5 | 3 | 330656 | null |
| 6 | 3 | null | 174799 |

etc...

I can see that this likely has to do with the fact that I grouped by 'weekday' *and* 'member_casual', however I get errors if remove 'member casual' from the GROUP BY statement. I have tried to play around with a CASE IF statement instead, but have yet to find a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want `countif()`:

```
SELECT weekday, 
       COUNTIF(member_casual = 'member') AS member_total,
       COUNTIF(member_casual = 'casual') AS casual_total,
FROM`case-study-319921.2020_2021_Trip_Data.2020_2021_Rides_Merged`
GROUP BY weekday;
```

Comment: That worked! Thank you. How would I go about adding two columns representing the daily averages by day of week of both casual and members?

Comment: @JeffHenry . . . You should ask new questions as *questions* not comments.